What does it mean to “kill” the first homology?
I am new to homology, and want to understand what it means when one says “kill” a homology group? Specifically I came across this in the context where I read that attaching 2-cells to each cycle in a weakly fundamental basis, trivializes the fundamental group. But for other arbitrary cycle bases, attaching 2-cells only “kills” the first homology.
I interpret 2-cells to simply mean ‘rectangles’ that I add to a cycle basis, but I am not familiar with what the “kill” terminology implies

It means that the $H_1$ of the resulting space is trivial.

Rephrasing that, does that mean the resulting space has effectively one non-trivial loop (all other loops can be deformed to a single loop)?

One non-trivial loop means non-trivial $H_1$.

okay, so trivial $H_1$ means no non-trivial loops and any loop can be deformed to a point. For example like on a sphere?

@Arthur Careful; that sounds more like $\pi_1$. There is some ambiguity. $H_1$ is the Abelianisation of $\pi_1$ only, and nontrivial groups with trivial Abelianisation exist

@clearski Just be careful with what 'nontrivial' means. The rules for the fundamental group of loops up to based homotopy are not the same as for the rules of the first homology group

But, if $\pi_1(X)=0$ then $H_1(X)=0$ assuming path connectivity

Thanks @FShrike! So, killing the fundamental group implies killing the first homology, but not necessarily the other way around.

I want to understand when the opposite happens- ie one “kills” the first homology without trivializing the fundamental group.

@clearski If you do this in the most conservative way, by picking a presentation of $[\pi_1 X, \pi_1 X]$, extending it to a presentation of $\pi_1(X)$, and then attaching cells to kill all generators in the second presentation that are not in the first, then you should be left with only $[\pi_1 X, \pi_1 X]$. But really, if you're interested in these things you should ask another question.
